# Front page 2003: how to line up forms vertically

Tags: frontpage

I am trying to creating a form on Frontpage 2003 and right now all my boxes are all over the place, as shown below:

Name:    [----]
Email:     [----]

I want the boxes to be like this:

Name:    [----]
Email:   [----]

I have tried using table to line up the boxes but when it come to giving an ID using the 'Lable' on the 'Form' tool bar by highlighting the text box and 'Name', the table get highlighted and wont create an lable.

I just want to line up vertically all the boxes and i am new to web design so i dont understand much about HTML or CSS. I dont think Frontpage 2003 has CSS.

Can someone tell me how to line up all my boxes. Many thankz

Answer (score 0):

First, stop using Front page 2003.  Download Microsoft Web Developer Express 2010 for free from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/#2010-Visual-Web-Developer

Second, take a look at this resource which will show you how to use CSS with forms:

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-forms.shtml